# Word for false, self-perpetuating "cure"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There are situations where a short-term remedy actually perpetuates the underlying long term problem.

For example, drinking more coffee is a kind of false cure for a caffeine withdrawal headache.

Similarly, scratching at a rash can make it feel better in the moment, but often perpetuates the rash.

Is there an adjective or phrase for these activities that seem good, but are actually deceptive and counterproductive?  (E.g. "Scratching an inflamed rash is an [something] activity.")

Comment: *A remedy that aggravates the malady (/disease)*

Comment: Homeopathy? Alternative Medicine?

Comment: "hair of the dog that bit you"? "snake oil"?

Comment: There is the concept of *Trojan horse* - something masquerading as a gift that contains destruction.

Comment: Paradoxical? Any symptoms that arise as a result of medication that are actually the same as the symptoms it's supposed to treat are called paradoxical symptoms/effects.

Comment: Few of the offered terms actually match your request exactly -- they focus on the self-defeating aspect, but don't capture the idea that it *does* provide relief in the short term.  To emphasize that you might just want to pile on an adjective like "shortsighted" or "myopic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Counterproductive - Having the opposite of the desired effect.

Comment: +1 This is the only and best answer. Mari's definition describes the conundrum *exactly*, there are no viable alternatives. It just so happens that the answer is already present in the question!

Comment: @Mari-LouA While this answer does seem to be on point, the OP knows this word and wants something else. And while you might think it best, *only* is a bit strong. Your answer would be perfectly fine in many circumstances.

Comment: @bib Right.  "Counterproductive" is a great word, but I am curious if there is a word that emphasizes something that is _deceptively_ counterproductive.  Thanks!

Comment: @elliot42 See Further Supplement in my answer.

Comment: @elliot42 Your request for a word that is *deceptively counter-productive* is self-defeating. :)

Answer (score 14):

I think your best bet would be [self defeating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-defeating):

> Injurious to one's or its own purposes or welfare: "American officials will find it harder than ever to ward off self-defeating protectionist measures"

Answer (score 3):

For many drugs and activities there is a [*rebound effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebound_effect).  This is characterized by

> the emergence or re-emergence of symptoms that were either absent or controlled while taking a medication, but appear when that same medication is discontinued, or reduced in dosage. In the case of re-emergence, the severity of the symptoms are often worse than pretreatment levels.

This can apply to many different activities, such as energy conservation (more insulation and attendant savings leads to more usage) and traffic patterns (increased roadway capacity leads to more traffic) as discussed [here](http://www.vtpi.org/tdm/tdm64.htm).

SUPPLEMENT

There is also a principle known as *[unintended consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences)* for

> outcomes that are not the ones intended by a purposeful action.

This concept applies to a broader range of outcomes than a direct exacerbation of the initial problem and might even include inintended benefits.

FURTHER SUPPLEMENT

In light of OP's comment, consider the adjective *insidious*.  [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/insidious) defines it as

> Working or spreading harmfully in a subtle or stealthy manner: *insidious rumors; an insidious disease.*

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insidious) defines it as

> something that is dangerous because it seems to be harmless or not important but in fact causes harm or damage
>   *the insidious effects of gossip*

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insidious) offers these two definitions

> 1. stealthy, subtle, cunning, or treacherous
> 2. working in a subtle or apparently innocuous way, but nevertheless deadly *an insidious illness*

Comment: Well known side effect of xylometazoline nose spray to relieve congestion is the rebound congestion or so called "Otrivin Addiction"

Comment: You don't say "scratching an inflamed rash is an insidious activity". Insidious is fine to describe different maladies. Can we say "the *insidious* effects of scratching"? Really?

Comment: @Mari-LouA In his comment on Mari's answer, the OP specifically says he wants to emphasize *deceptive*. And you often hear about *insidious* effects of a given habit.

Answer (score 2):

Exacerbate.

"Trying to cure my headaches with caffeine only exacerbates the problem, because caffeine is known to cause a rebound of your headache."

"Scratching the rash will only exacerbate it"

Answer (score 2):

It's not an exact match, but a [quick fix](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick+fix?s=t) is something that provides a temporary solution but which is acknowledged not to address the actual problem. However, if you want to explicitly imply that the action actually makes matters worse then one of the other answers may be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

**Perverse** is often used to describe something that has the opposite of the intended effect.

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perverse), the first definition:

> per·verse [per-vurs] (adjective) willfully determined or disposed to
>   go counter to what is expected or desired; contrary.

The same link goes into the origin of the word:

> 1325–75; Middle English  < Latin perversus  facing the wrong way,
>   askew, orig. past participle of pervertere.  See [pervert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervert)

While the words perversion and pervert are often tied to topics of sexual [deviancy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deviance), its underlying meaning can be more directly associated with the word *[misguided](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Misguided)* (which is indicated as a synonym of *perverted*).

So you can say someone is misguided if they think continually scratching an itch would be beneficial. You would say that scratching has the perverse effect of ultimately causing harm.

Examples of *perverse* being used this way are not hard to find.

Here is one titled "[The Affordable Care Act's Perverse Incentives](http://www.law.berkeley.edu/files/bclbe/DavidGamage_How_the_Affordable_Care_Act_Will_Create_May2012.pdf)" which describes the counterintuitive effects of a law this way (in it's second paragraph):

> While recognizing the importance of these improvements, this Essay
>   focuses on how the ACA will also create perverse incentives harming
>   low- and moderate-income workers. This Essay explains how the ACA will
>   impose effective taxes with respect to low- and moderate-income
>   workers, thereby reducing these workers’ employment opportunities and
>   creating a number of other economic and social harms.

Here is another, "[Perverse Habits: The G8 and Subsidies That Harm Forests and Economies](http://www.wri.org/publication/perverse-habits)" It begins:

> In 1998 the leaders of the Group of Eight (Japan, France, the United
>   States, Great Britain, Germany, Italy, Canada and Russia) committed to
>   actions that would help protect the world’s forests. Some G8 members,
>   however, continue to provide large and perverse subsidies to forest
>   products industries promoting programs that undermine forest
>   protection and accelerate forest loss.

More examples are given in the section titled "[Perverse Results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences#Perverse_results)" in the Wikipedia article on Unintended consequences.

The term *[perverse incentive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_incentive)* is described as

> an incentive that has an unintended and undesirable result which is
>   contrary to the interests of the incentive makers.

**[Cobra Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_effect)**

Interestingly, the links on *unintended consequences* and *perverse incentive* lead to **Cobra Effect**, which has a fascinating origin:

> The cobra effect occurs when an attempted solution to a problem
>   actually makes the problem worse.

I won't quote the origin, which is worth reading at that link, but it has to do with how incentivizing the killing of cobras to reduce their abundance eventually led to the breading of them, which led to other unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

***'snake oil'*** is an appropriate literal and metaphorical phrase for a cure-all elixir of unproven worth, and would encompass a remedy that carries short-term placebo effects.

Answer (score 1):

Related terms include:
***patent medicine***,
***quack remedy***, and 
***home remedy***

Patent medicines (and the related terms) are cures that do not work as promoted (not to be confused with patents given to pharmaceutical companies) were referred to as ***nostrum*** or 'our medicine'.

Answer (score 0):

***Futile***

If you have conjunctivitis, you might have the urge to rub your eyes. An atopic dermatitis (atopic eczema) produces an urge to scratch that can sometimes be unbearable.

> The skin of a patient with atopic dermatitis [...] It is sometimes called "the itch that rashes" because the itchiness precedes the rash, and **scratching the itchy skin may cause the rash**.

Difficulty in hearing might convince some to remove excessive earwax by using cotton swabs (UK cotton buds) which more often than not results in pushing the cerumen further down the ear canal. Acne sufferers will often squeeze or pop their spots in a vain attempt to reduce the redness and remove the white pus.

Scratching, rubbing, popping ... are not "cures" by any stretch of the imagination. On the contrary they serve only to *aggravate* and *worsen* the condition and as, the OP stated, perpetuate the symptoms. In fact the activity of all these remedies can be said to be ***futile***.

---

ALTERNATIVES

Taking into consideration the OP wishes for a word or expression that emphasizes the deceptive nature of a counter-productive remedy (or urge) such as *scratching*, *rubbing*, *squeezing* or *popping*. I suggest the following:

- *Misguided behaviour .* ("Scratching an inflamed rash is a misguided solution.")

[***misguided***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misguided) *led or prompted by wrong or inappropriate motives or ideals, guide in the wrong direction;* I was misguided by websites dealing with acne that squeezing my spots could improve my skin condition.

- *A misleading antidote*. ("Scratching an inflamed rash is a misleading remedy.")

[***misleading***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misleading) : *to lead in a wrong direction or into a mistaken action or belief often by deliberate deceit*. Scratching might *mislead* you into thinking the itch will disappear or decrease in intensity.

---

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific instance of your general question, but could be applicable:

> In economics, the [Jevons paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jevons_paradox) (/ˈdʒɛvənz/; sometimes Jevons effect)
>   is the proposition that technological progress that increases the
>   efficiency with which a resource is used tends to increase (rather
>   than decrease) the rate of consumption of that resource.[1] In 1865,
>   the English economist William Stanley Jevons observed that
>   technological improvements that increased the efficiency of coal use
>   led to increased consumption of coal in a wide range of industries. He
>   argued that, contrary to common intuition, technological improvements
>   could not be relied upon to reduce fuel consumption.[2]

Or perhaps just "paradox."

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that 'nostrum' is closest concise word to what you are looking for. ([*nostrum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nostrum): "A medicine or remedy in conventional use which has not been proven to have any desirable medical effects.")

Comment: Please offer some evidence to support your answer.

Comment: Just look it up, for example [in a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostrum)

Comment: Sure, except that you as the answer writer are supposed to do that research and include it in your answer. You could edit and incorporate that link.

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, something that makes the condition worse is [contraindicated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contraindicate), but the word does not imply that it perpetuates the symptoms.

Answer (score -4):

"Old wives' tale" comes to mind. Also, I didn't see "counteractive" mentioned in the answers above. I liked the inquirer's "self-perpetuating" modifier the best, actually. Sometimes the best 'word' for something is the definition, itself.

- Meredith Greene